# What open source multivariate or a/b testing frameworks or libraries are available?

Tags: optimization, frameworks

Google Website Optimizer http://www.google.com/websiteoptimizer and Visual Website Optimizer http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/ both allow me to run experiments for individual sections of content on web pages.  But, what libraries or frameworks are available for running tests on things other than snippets of HTML?

In other words, are there open source projects which provide the underpinning logic and calculations required to build my own multivariate tests?

One such library is ABingo http://www.bingocardcreator.com/abingo in Ruby.  But, what other libraries/frameworks are available?

Comment: There are couple of resources listed on my blog here: http://www.wingify.com/conversion-blog/15-free-ab-split-testing-resources/

Comment: Google Website Optimizer is now unavailable as of 8/1/12
Some, but not all the functionality is incorporated into 'Experiments' feature of Google Analytics

Answer (score 5):

From this mashable article [a-b-testing-resources](http://mashable.com/2010/11/04/a-b-testing-resources/) I ended up finding [vanity](http://vanity.labnotes.org/metrics.html) and  [genetify](https://github.com/gregdingle/genetify/wiki/). Vanity has a prettier documentation but genetify looks like solid code.

Both are hosted on Github which is always a plus, and of course a lot of A/B testing is done on HTML snippets but I think both of these are extensible enough so that you could possibly enhance or customize them to suit your needs if they don't do so out of the box.

[Vanity Screenshot](http://vanity.labnotes.org/index.html#intro)

[sidebar_test.png http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/7246/sidebartest.png](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/7246/sidebartest.png)

[Genetify Demo](http://app.genetify.com/demo/)
[screenshot-with-shadow.png http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/4526/screenshotwithshadow.png](http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/4526/screenshotwithshadow.png)

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise against using Google Website Optimizer and other javascript-based A/B packages.  They drag your site's performance down and kill off any SEO you might have had, both of which affect your bottom line.  Since you're probably using AB testing to make your site better at converting random strangers to money, it would seem counterproductive to do anything that damages that.

Look into something that runs on the server, such as  [ABingo for Rails](http://www.bingocardcreator.com/abingo) and [FairlyCertain for ASP.NET](http://www.fairtutor.com/fairlycertain/).  Both of those are open source and free.

Comment: I don't think I agree with the SEO argument, you can have stable defaults, and original pieces of HTML that are on the page that you want to improve upon you can swap that out for similar content, you're really not taking a hit when it comes to SEO. As for performance it's just like any other javascript related thing you have on your page.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found a Ruby on Rails gem **[Mountain Goat](https://rubygems.org/gems/mountain-goat)** which provides in-house a/b testing and high-quality analytics for any Rails application.  Mountain Goat provides an entire suite built into your application to manipulate and play around with your a/b test and conversion data.